# I have a TTY after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, lightdm, tty

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, I have logged into `tty1` and now I have this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-generic i686)

[Some more text in here]

user@localhost:~$
```

What do I type after `$` to get to my usual desktop?

Comment: What do you want to do now that your there?

Comment: The `$` is your Bash shell's command prompt. You can now enter any terminal command, just like into the terminal emulator of a desktop environment. What exactly did you want to do? Were you having a desktop installation before the upgrade and now it only boots to text mode? Please explain your situation and intents.

Comment: I upgraded from 14.04 on my Acer Aspire 5733Z to 16.04 and then restarted my laptop. When it came on and I got through the tty1 log in, I now have to put in command " me@me-aspire-5337z~$". What do I put? I am just trying to get in after a restart.

Comment: @Guido322 What happens if you type `sudo service lightdm start`, then enter your password? That will attempt to start `lightdm`, the graphical desktop manager.

Comment: Now I have- start: missing job name.

Comment: Are there perhaps error messages from the upgrade that you have not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

1. After opening a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, as you have already done,  at the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. After you have logged in in the console type:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up your default purple login screen and then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment as usual.
4. If you get stuck in a login loop at the login screen due to a problem that occurred upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, you can fix it by following the instructions in the answers to this question: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).